# msbuild output varies in cruise control .net

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol, ccnet-config, web-compiler

When I run Cruise Control .Net, msbuild does not behave the same as when I run directly from command line on the same machine with same exact options. What started me looking into this is that WebCompiler was not running when ccnet ran msbuild against my solution. However, when I run from command line WebCompiler builds runs just fine. I ran with the /verbosity:diagnostic and /fl options and noticed a big difference in the output between msbuild within commandline and msbuild within ccnet. We are also running Rebuild, Release, and "Any CPU". We don't have Visual Studio installed on the CI server, just Microsoft Build Tools 2015.

What is so special about the way CCNet runs msbuild???

Command line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild" mysolution.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU" /tv:14.0 /t:Rebuild
```

vs. CruiseControl.Net:

```
<msbuild>
    <buildArgs>/p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU" /tv:14.0</buildArgs>
    <executable>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe</executable>
    <targets>Rebuild</targets>
    <projectFile>mysolution.sln</projectFile>
</msbuild>
```

Comment: Might be running under a different user account, and with different command line opptions. Use e.g. process explorer to inspect that.